# getters and Setters in c#

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me what this Console application does? What is actually happening?

Also, There are errors. Can you please fix them?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Name n = new Name[5]; // error
        n[0] = new Name(0); //error
        n[0] = "hgfhf"; //is this possible in this program?
        string nam = n[0];
    }
}
public class Name
{
    private string[] name;
    private int size;
    public Name(int size)
    {
        this.name = new string[size];
        this.size = size;
    }
    public string this[int pos] // what does this mean?
    {
        get
        {
            return name[pos];
        }
        set
        {
            name[pos] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please drop the txtspk, it only makes it hard to read what you are trying to say.

Comment: If you want to use StackOverflow, please put some effort into your questions. I've just *translated* it for you; do not use 'text' speech and at least try to use correct spelling and punctuation.

Comment: Please elaborate on your questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). It's like a normal property but it allows you to use the `[]` syntax on it:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a Name instance by calling it's constructor
        // capable of storing 1 string
        Name n = new Name(1);

        // Store a string in the name
        n[0] = "hgfhf";

        // Retrieve the stored string
        string nam = n[0];
    }
}

public class Name
{
    private string[] names;
    private int size;

    public Name(int size)
    {
        // initialize the names array for the given size
        this.names = new string[size];

        // store the size in a private field
        this.size = size;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indexer property allowing to access the private names array
    /// given an index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pos">The index to access the array</param>
    /// <returns>The value stored at the given position</returns>
    public string this[int pos]
    {
        get
        {
            return names[pos];
        }
        set
        {
            names[pos] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Name n = new Name[5]; //this is declaration error
```

--> You need to declare an array of class Name .

Declare it as:

```
Name[] n = new Name[5];


public string this[int pos] {}
```

This means you have defined an indexer property and indexers allow instances of a `class` or `struct` to be indexed just like arrays.

Now you are assigning a string value (`string nam = n[0]`) which is all correct as the property has been defined.

Comment: Ripper, click Edit and look at the help column at the right

Answer (score 0):

```
Name n = new Name[5];//error
```

The variable `n` is a reference to a single instance of `Name`, so you can't put an array in it. Use `Name[]` as the type for the variable.

```
n[0] = new Name(0);//error
```

This error will go away when you make the variable an array.

```
n[0] = "hgfhf";//is this possible in this program??
```

No, that would try to replace the `Name` instance with a string. If you want to put the string in the `Name` instance you use double indexes, one index to access the item in the array, and one index to access the indexer property in the `Name` instance:

```
n[0][0] = "asdf";
```

(However, as you have specified a size of zero for the `Name` instance, this would cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.)

```
public string this[int pos]//wt this means????
```

This is the indexer property. It's a property with a parameter, and it's usually used to access items as if the object was an array.